# php5-fpm spawning multiple times

Tags: ubuntu, fastcgi

On my 512MB ram server memory use was at 50%. I installed fastcgi and php5-fpm and now the server memory is report 137%.

See below for results of 'top'. Currently I have a site in apache being served by nginx as a reverse proxy. But the site currently is just one index.html file with a couple words in it.

To note I followed these instructions to set the fastcgi and php5-fpm up: http://alexcabal.com/installing-apache-mod_fastcgi-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-server-maverick/

```
    1 root      15   0 23560 1644 1316 S    0  0.2   0:01.23 init                                  
 1136 root      15   0 18888 1012  784 S    0  0.1   0:00.07 cron                                  
 1202 mysql     15   0  183m  23m 6768 S    0  2.6   0:02.70 mysqld                                
 1210 root      15   0 49424 2668 2108 S    0  0.3   0:05.41 sshd                                  
 1231 syslog    15   0 12536  796  600 S    0  0.1   0:00.30 syslogd                               
 1297 root      15   0 84088  21m 1604 S    0  2.3   0:05.56 miniserv.pl                           
 3748 root      16   0 70764 3308 2568 S    0  0.3   0:00.02 sshd                                  
 3760 hmark     15   0 70764 1632  888 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 sshd                                  
 3761 hmark     15   0 20924 2360 1616 S    0  0.2   0:00.01 bash                                  
 3950 root      15   0 71536 3324 2580 S    0  0.4   0:00.02 sshd                                  
 3962 hmark     18   0 71536 1652  892 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 sshd                                  
 3963 hmark     16   0 20924 2356 1616 S    0  0.2   0:00.01 bash                                  
 3987 hmark     15   0 19180 1360 1068 R    0  0.1   0:00.13 top                                   
 9753 root      18   0 54900 1228  352 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 nginx                                 
 9754 www-data  18   0 55240 2120  948 S    0  0.2   0:00.49 nginx                                 
 9755 www-data  18   0 55240 2116  948 S    0  0.2   0:00.44 nginx                                 
 9756 www-data  15   0 55240 2132  948 S    0  0.2   0:00.43 nginx                                 
 9757 www-data  18   0 55240 1668  504 S    0  0.2   0:00.59 nginx                                 
32650 root      18   0 86460 4408 2736 S    0  0.5   0:00.01 apache2                               
32653 www-data  25   0 85016 2172  524 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 apache2                               
32654 www-data  18   0 85016 2112  468 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 apache2                               
32656 www-data  15   0 86192 2112  468 S    0  0.2   0:00.01 apache2                               
32658 www-data  18   0  302m 4088 1568 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 apache2                               
32660 www-data  25   0  302m 4240 1564 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 apache2                               
32742 root      18   0  121m 4216 1256 S    0  0.4   0:00.12 php5-fpm                              
32743 www-data  18   0  121m 5476 2332 S    0  0.6   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32744 www-data  18   0  121m 4464 1468 S    0  0.5   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32745 www-data  18   0  121m 4460 1464 S    0  0.5   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32746 www-data  18   0  121m 4464 1468 S    0  0.5   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32747 www-data  25   0  121m 3740  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32748 www-data  25   0  121m 3740  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32750 www-data  25   0  121m 3740  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32752 www-data  25   0  121m 3740  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32753 www-data  25   0  121m 3740  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32754 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32755 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32756 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32757 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32758 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32759 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32760 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32761 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32762 www-data  18   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32763 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm                              
32764 www-data  25   0  121m 3744  784 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 php5-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP FPM will indeed spawn multiple processes, it spreads requests across them all.

You should be able to adjust how many spawn by editing `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Comment: But to go from 50% memory use to 137% memory use can't be the expected default behavior right? Even when I disable the php5-fpm service now it shows 126% memory usage. Where is before I tried the steps in the article above I was getting 50% memory roughly. When looking in top nothing appears to be using much of any memory though that I can see. All .4% kinda thing.

Comment: What does `free -m` say? Where are you getting the 126% figure from?

Comment: From the MediaTemple control panel. free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           924        699        224          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        699        224
Swap:            0          0          0

Comment: Also sudo cat /proc/user_beancounters shows lockedpages                     0                    0                  600                  600                   20
            privvmpages                179205               179356               236586               249036                  150
            shmpages                     9324                 9324                15000                15000                   16

Comment: So looks like privvmpages is going way over, but never even heard of that, and the changes I made today from the link above never asked me to install or modify anything called privvmpages.

Comment: If you're seeing 669MB of 924MB used you're hardly using 126% of RAM.

Comment: My server allows me 512RM, but it lets you go over temporarily up to 1GB. So on 512MB Ram, 669MB Ram sounds like about 126%. But that part I know my question is why after just enabling the fastcgi and php5-fpm it causing the privvmpages and memory to go incredibly high?